# Openshift cartridge deploying to wrong/old app

Tags: python, git, flask, redis, openshift

After accidentally damaging my flask app on openshift I deleted it and am trying to rebuild it. I believe I have installed it correctly by creating a new python app, then performing:

```
$ git remote set-url origin ssh://55ddee2489f5.......@myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/~/git/myapp.git/
$ git push -f origin master
```

then

```
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://55ddee248........c@myflaskapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/~/git/myflaskapp.git/
 + 068620c...00df6fb master -> master (forced update)
```

Next I want to add a redis cartridge.

```
$ rhc add-cartridge http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect\?github\=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart
The cartridge 'http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart' will be downloaded and installed
Adding http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart to application 'myflaskapp' ... Application '5585ab144.......'
not found.
```

As you can see the cartridge is being deployed to the old location '5585ab144.......', not ssh://55ddee248........c@myflaskapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/~/git/myflaskapp.git/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same DNS (`application`) name (`app-domain.rhcloud.com`) that your old application was using, you need to wait for the DNS to update and point to the new application. It could take up to 24 hours, but usually it just takes a couple of hours.

Comment: Yes I did use the same myapp-mydomain combination. I'll check back later. thank you.

Comment: Finally worked when i did : $ rhc add-cartridge http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect\?github\=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart --app myapp